# How can i use response.redirect from inside a function defined in Class file in c# 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have a simple function `GetPageName(String PageFileName, String LangCode)` defined inside a class file. I call this function from `default.aspx.cs` file, In this function I am not able to use `Response.Redirect("Error.aspx")` to show user that error has been generated.

Below is example of Code

```
public static string GetPageName(String PageFileName, String LangCode)
{
     String sLangCode = Request("Language");
     String pgName = null;
     if ( sLangCode.Length > 6)
     {
        Reponse.Redirect("Error.aspx?msg=Invalid Input");
     }
     else
     {
         try
         {            
             String strSql = "SELECT* FROM Table";

             Dataset ds = Dataprovider.Connect_SQL(strSql);

         }
         catch( Exception ex)
         {
            response.redirect("Error.aspx?msg="+ex.Message);
         }
     }
     return pgName;
}
```

I have may function defined in Business and Datalayer where i want to trap the error and redirect user to the Error page.

Comment: That's bad design.  The business layer should not know about ASP.Net

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Why are you having the business and/or data layer controlling the UI?  Why not have the layer/class return an error, and let the presentation layer/application determine what to do?

Comment: Don't show error message to users.

Comment: You should use a more general error page, and preferably ELMAH.

Comment: @Slaks: I am new to C# and still learning problem is that i call a function from codedehind which call business logic and if business logic is fine then it call a function in the dataLayer and so on. My problem is that if it generate error in Datalayer it passes boolean value back to the Business Logic layer and business Logic layer passes value back to the presentation layer. Now if the error is generated in Data Layer it return false & user doesn't come to know what error. So how should i handle error handling from layer to layer. an Example would be great

Comment: The user _should not_ see error details.  Error details can contain sensitive information.  However, the proper way to do this is to just let the exception propagate up.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for that. Although I have not used it before, I recently showed the error and reminded myself after seeing your comment to hide the error message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("error.aspx");
```

to use it your assembly should reference System.Web.

Comment: Excellent, but @StudentDubai- you should think scalability and whatif? (Risks). Folks told you precious ideas you should think about.

Comment: Thank you. +1 for the quick line.

Answer (score 4):

For a start, in one place you're trying to use:

```
response.redirect(...);
```

which wouldn't work anyway - C# is case-sensitive.

But the bigger problem is that normally `Response.Redirect` uses the [`Page.Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.response.aspx) property to get at the relevant [`HttpResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx). That isn't available when you're not in a page, of course.

Options:

- Use `HttpContext.Current.Response` to get at the response for the current response for the executing thread
- Pass it into the method as a parameter:

  ```
  // Note: parameter names changed to follow .NET conventions
  public static string GetPageName(String pageFileName, String langCode,
                                   HttpResponse response)
  {
      ...
      response.Redirect(...);
  }
  ```

(EDIT: As noted in comments, you also have a SQL Injection vulnerability. Please use parameterized SQL. Likewise showing exception messages directly to users can be a security vulnerability in itself...)

Comment: He has even bigger problems :)

Comment: @SLaks: True - hadn't spotted the SQL Injection. Eek.

Comment: @Slaks: I can check for SQL injection or convert all sql to Store Procedure which will take care of sql injection but i want to inform users if error is generated in Data layer how can i achieve that in best possible manner. Example would be great based on above code example

Comment: @StudentDubai: Stored procs don't stop SQL injection; you need to use parameters.  You should throw exceptions from the business layer, and use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx to show an error page.

Comment: @StudentDubai: You don't *check* for SQL Injection - you use parameterized queries to avoid them in the first place. You should certainly inform users that something went wrong - but that doesn't mean you have to expose the exception message directly. It's intended for developers, not users. You also shouldn't usually catch plain `Exception` - catch exceptions you *expect* and can handle; let other exceptions propagate up the stack, have a top-level exception handler specified in your web config to display a generic error message; log the details for diagnostics with something like ELMAH.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Note that ELMAH does not help display error pages, AFAIK.  It just does reporting.